# iPhone 5S Blocked numbers

Tags: iphone, ios

Instead of that person not knowing that they have been blocked, is there a wayto set up your iPhone to send an auto-response to someone that they have indeed been blocked?  Similar to email when one goes on vacation, they get an automatic response that they will be out of the office.

Does anyone know how to send an auto response to someone that has been blocked?

Answer (score 2):

If you've blocked them on your iPhone then there's no way to send them any type of auto-response.